# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1, 2, 3' to data type int

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I can't seem to find a solution to this problem. Following is my query:

```
Declare @MY_STUDENT_ID  Varchar(100)

Select @MY_STUDENT_ID = COALESCE(@MY_STUDENT_ID + ',', '') + Convert(varchar, STUDENT_ID) From Some_TABLE Where FISCAL_YEAR = '2014'

SELECT * FROM Table_Students WHERE STUDENT_ID IN (@MY_STUDENT_ID)
```

Basically first query runs and give me all student IDs as a string concatenated with , for e.g. 1,2,3

And then this value is passed into second query but second query is giving this error which I have posted in title. No idea what to do so any help will be appreciated.

Type of STUDENT_ID field is int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do so using dynamic SQL, but in this scenario, Martin SMith's answer seems to be better. Should you, however, wish to use dynamic SQL, this would be the way to do so (untested pseudo-code):

```
Declare @MY_STUDENT_ID  varchar(100);
DECLARE @sql nvasrchar(max);

Select @MY_STUDENT_ID = COALESCE(@MY_STUDENT_ID + ',', '') + Convert(varchar, STUDENT_ID) From Some_TABLE Where FISCAL_YEAR = '2014'

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM Table_Students WHERE STUDENT_ID IN (' + @MY_STUDENT_ID + ')';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 4):

There is absolutely no need to mess about with comma delimited lists here.

Just use the sub query directly

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_Students 
WHERE STUDENT_ID IN (SELECT StudentId 
                     From Some_TABLE Where FISCAL_YEAR = '2014')
```

Your approach does not work as it ends up generating something with semantics of

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_Students 
WHERE STUDENT_ID IN ('1,2,3')
```

Which is not the same as

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_Students 
WHERE STUDENT_ID IN (1,2,3)
```

As it just is a single string parameter with contents that happen to resemble an in list, rather than 3 int parameters.

Comment: Yes I know this is the proper way but I wanted to learn if I can also do it that way like I have posted above.

Comment: Only by dynamic SQL which should be avoided here.